# Convert Only Time to The Relevent Timezone

Tags: javascript, momentjs, moment-timezone

I am using moment js to get only the UTC time.

```
const time = moment().utc().format('HH:mm:ss');
```

example output is like this - "07:57:49"

I want to change this time value to relevant timezone value.

```
const americaTime = moment(time).tz("America/Los_Angeles").format();
```

But there is an warning saying - "Deprecation warning: value provided is not in a recognized RFC2822 or ISO format. moment construction falls back to js Date(), which is not reliable across all browsers and versions. Non RFC2822/ISO date formats are discouraged. Is there any alternative way to overcome this issue ?

Comment: try `moment().utc().tz("America/Los_Angeles").format();`

Comment: Does this answer your question [Convert date to another timezone in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18612568/14733216)?

Comment: You need to specify the format `HH:mm:ss` in the second param!

Answer (score 1):

do this

```js
let time = moment().utc().tz("America/Los_Angeles").format('HH:mm:ss');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const time = moment().utc().format('HH:mm:ss');

moment(time,'HH:mm:ss').tz("America/Los_Angeles").format();
```

You need to specify the format `HH:mm:ss` in the second param, momentjs throws this error because it is unable to parse the input without the format!

Answer (score 0):

You can also display the time UTC, or in any IANA timezone with vanilla JS, using [`Date.toLocaleTimeString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleTimeString):

```js
let dt = new Date();

const timeZones = ['UTC', 'America/Los_Angeles', 'America/New_York'];

console.log('Time zone'.padEnd(20), 'Current time')
for(let timeZone of timeZones) {
    console.log(timeZone.padEnd(20), dt.toLocaleTimeString('en', {  timeZone, hourCycle: 'h24', hour: '2-digit', minute: '2-digit', second: '2-digit' }));
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; }
```